# EWS Managed API - Filter items by body

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have 1100 appointments in the outlook calendar, 330 of them has category = "concrete_category" and body = "concrete_body".

I am trying to filter calendar appointments by category and body substring using the following AQS:

> "category:{concrete_category} AND body:\"{concrete_body}\""

I expect to receive 330 items, but Outlook returns me only 250 appointments and cache the response. So if I change appointment body or category, outlook will return the same appointments as for the previous query but with updated categories and body that doesn't match the aqs filter. And I have to refilter them on the client side.

How to prevent query caching and exceed the limit of 250 appointments? I don't have this problem when I don't use filter by body.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the Cache by using the ResetCache Attribute of the QueryString element https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/exchangewebservices.querystringtype.resetcache(v=exchg.150).aspx. Unfortunately the EWS Managed API doesn't expose this so you would need to use SOAP or proxy code [EWS API Search Filter does not return all information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507694/ews-api-search-filter-does-not-return-all-information) or modify the source of the EWS Managed API from the github repo.

The 250 limit is normal but you should be able just to page through to get the next 250 items.

Comment: I rewrote my code to send soap string with reset cache flag and set page size equals to 1000,  but outlook still returns me 250 appointments in response with false 'hasLastItemInResponse' flag. I have added new valid appointments to calendar but it returned me only 250 items again.

Comment: 250 is the correct behaviour this is a restriction for EWS and throttling when using AQS and body. If hasLastItemInResponse is false then there are more items you can retrieve so just get the next page of 250.